# conversion from ‘std::wstring {aka std::basic_string<wchar_t>}’ to non-scalar type ‘UString {aka std::basic_string<char>}’

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Can you please tell me what's the wrong this code and Any ideas on how to fix?

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_COM_DEMO_TEST_SEND (JNIEnv
*env, jclass c, jstring param){
    const char* strParam = env->GetStringUTFChars(param, 0);
    UString data = s2ws(string(strParam));
    UString result = TEST::SEND(data);
    return env->NewStringUTF(ws2s(result).c_str());
}
```

i got following error.

```
error: conversion from ‘std::wstring {aka std::basic_string<wchar_t>}’ to non-scalar type ‘UString {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
  UString data = s2ws(string(strParam));
```

Comment: `#ifdef WIN32
typedef std::wstring UString;
#else
typedef std::string UString;
#endif`

Comment: Then you compile your code without `WIN32` set, check your project settings.

Comment: i compile it on Linux  and like this
`g++ -Wall -g -c -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux BridgePosAPI.cpp -o BridgePosAPI.o -std=c++11`

Comment: if its in linux what should be Ustring?

Comment: Are you cross compiling for a windows target? Otherwise I'd leave out the windows specific stuff.

Comment: As the `s2ws()` function seems to promise it should be `std::wstring`.

Comment: actually i wanna compile it in linux and  get so file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty good, actually; you're trying to use a `std::string` but you have a `std::wstring`, and the compiler doesn't know how to convert one into the other.

The fact that they're both specializations of `std::basic_string` does not mean that they are interchangeable.